# Pass sequence of IRIs as values in binding variable to sem:sparql function - marklogic

Tags: marklogic

I am using ML version `8.0-6.3`

What I need is to pass sequence of `IRIs` as values in binding variable to `sem:sparql` which will be used in `filter` clause.

for example:

```
let $params := 
    map:new((
        map:entry("narrowersQuery", ("term:56564", "term:56564"))
    ))

return 
sem:sparql(
  "
    PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#> 
    PREFIX term: <http://www.test.com/term/>

    SELECT ?iri ?pl
    WHERE {
        ?iri skos:prefLabel ?pl .
        ?iri skos:narrower ?narrower .
        filter (?narrower in (?narrowersQuery))
        # ?narrowersQuery should be treated as (term:56564, term:56564)
    } limit 10
  ", 
  $params
)
```

Above query should return the IRIs having narrower predicate objects in (term:56564, term:56564) sequence.

Please help me if there is any way to achieve this.

I came across `sem:sparql-values` but that one is also not working, might be I am using that function in the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically use the `=` rather than the `IN` operator for this, which has done the trick for me in various occasions.

You likely also want to pass in `sem:iri`'s, rather than strings, something like this:

```
import module namespace sem = "http://marklogic.com/semantics" 
  at "/MarkLogic/semantics.xqy";

declare namespace term = "http://www.test.com/term/";

let $params := 
    map:new((
        map:entry("narrowersQuery", (sem:curie-expand("term:56564"), sem:curie-expand("term:56564")))
    ))

return 
sem:sparql(
  "
    PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>

    SELECT ?iri ?pl
    WHERE {
        ?iri skos:prefLabel ?pl .
        ?iri skos:narrower ?narrower .
        filter (?narrower = ?narrowersQuery)
    } limit 10
  ", 
  $params
)
```

HTH!